# Dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10, partitions not showing

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I would like to boot ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 which I did a clean install of after deleting all partitions on my hard drive. I made a bootable USB stick with the iso using Universal USB Installer, and shrunk C drive for free space to install Ubuntu.

However when starting the installation I get no options to wipe the hard drive or choose"Something else", it goes straight to the hard drive partition screen which is blank. When viewing the partitions through gparted everything looks fine but still nothing shows up on the partition screen. How can i fix this?

Edit: System is UEFI, Windows 10 mode is also in UEFI. I turned fast startup off.

sudo parted -l output

```
    Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB   523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   1001GB  1000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: Sony Storage Media (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  15.5GB  15.5GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS. Is Windows 10 install UEFI or BIOS? Post this: `sudo parted -l` Did you leave Windows fast startup on? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred I've edited the question. When entering sudo parted -1 it says the option -1 is invalid

Comment: Please copy & paste commands. It is an el or small L, not 1. If you do not know what parameters work with a command run man and command : `man parted`

Comment: @oldfred Oh okay. sorry. I edited the output in the question

Comment: You have UEFI with gpt partitioning, so be sure to boot in UEFI mode to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Did you turn off fast start up as linked to in first response. That is the usual reason for partitions not seen. Or Windows may be corrupted an need chkdsk.

Comment: @oldfred I did do everything mentioned, I ran chkdsk also. It stull doesn't show the hard drive partitions, it seems to show the USB drive partitions instead

Comment: Are you sure Windows fast start up is off? Link in first comment.